# jQuery cycle pager

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I got this pager working: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager6.html
But what if i have multiple slideshows on 1 page and i don't want to use an ID for the pager.
But use the nearest element with class X as pager.

Can this be done?

This is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.photoGallerySlideshowAlbum').cycle(
    {
        fx: 'fade',
        pager: '#photoGallerySlideshowPager',
        activePagerClass: 'selected',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide)
        { 
            return '#photoGallerySlideshowPager li:eq(' + idx + ') a';
        },
        after: function(currentImage, nextImage, options)
        {
            var captions = $(this).parent().parent().find('.photoGallerySlideshowCaptions').children().hide();
            var caption = $(captions[options.currSlide]);
            caption.show();
        }
    });
});
```

I did it now like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.photoGallerySlideshowAlbum').each(function(index, value)
    {
        var elPager = $(this).parent().find('.photoGallerySlideshowPager');

        $($(this)).cycle(
        {
            fx: 'fade',
            pager: elPager,
            activePagerClass: 'selected',
            pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide)
            { 
                return 'li:eq(' + idx + ') a';
            },
            after: function(currentImage, nextImage, options)
            {
                var captions = $(this).parent().parent().find('.photoGallerySlideshowCaptions').children().hide();
                var caption = $(captions[options.currSlide]);
                caption.show();
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

But i don't know how to change the pagerAnchorBuilder.
My html looks like this (can not be changed).

```
<div class="photoGallerySlideshowPager">
                    <ul>
<li><a href="#">a</a></li>
<li><a href="#">b</a></li>
<li><a href="#">c</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. You want multiple slideshows, right? couldn't you just create another one here? Am I missing something? And what do you mean you don't want to use an ID for the pager?

Comment: The pager property for jQuery cycle takes an id for an element in the demo, he wants to pass something that is relative to the current slider being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

In the jQuery cycle ref it states:

```
pager:         null,  // element, jQuery object, or jQuery selector string for the element to use as pager container
```

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

So you should be able to pass a jQuery object to this property like so:

```
pager: $(this).closest('.nav')
```